# Ignore files in build script - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, build-script

I have added few dummy responses as json files to test my application when the web services are down. While i generate the framework(iOS) i need to discard all the *.json files. Because having those files might get me problems in pen testing.

I am new to scripts & even I googled a bit, but couldn't get what i am searching for. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Select the files in the file organizer (left-hand panel). Make sure the File Inspector is open (right-hand panel, Cmd-Opt-1). Look for "Target Membership." Uncheck anything you don't want this copied into. You probably want it to be part of your test target, but not your framework target.

You can also look at the Build Phases for your target. Look for the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase and delete any files you don't want copied.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure

Xcode -> TARGETS
Click choose Target you want to remove resource -> Build Phases -> Delete resources no need build api.